# How to programatically access images in a resource file?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I have 30 PNGs in a resource file and I would like to iterate around them inside a timer. This timer sets the form's background image to the next PNG in the sequence to produce a basic animation.

I can't find an easy way to enumerate the resource file and get at the actual images.  I am also keen to keep the references to the images not fixed to their filenames so that updating the naming of the images within the Resource File would not require me to update this section of code.

**Notes:**

- The images inside the resource file are named in sequence ('image001.png', 'image002.png', ...).
- This resource file is used exclusively to store these images.

Comment: Check this blog out: [Social MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/5a38e44d-bb43-4434-b8d5-4246cdc7a97d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"), true, true);
        foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry img in list)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(img.Key);
            //use img.Value to get the bitmap
        }

    }
```

Comment: I understand this usage of resource files.  My question is about how  I would then extend this type of usage to say 'given the current image, move to the next image'?  Could you provide a code example?

Answer (score 1):

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
for(int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
{
  Stream file = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("NameSpace.Resources.Image"+i.ToString("000")+".png");
  // Do something or store the stream
}
```

To Get the name of all embedded resources:

```
string[] resourceNames = Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
foreach(string resourceName in resourceNames)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(resourceName);
}
```

Also, check out the [example](http://devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=75) in the Form1_Load function.

Comment: The only issue with this method (which will work) would be that if I rename the images (relatively likely to happen in this project) I have to come back and update the code.  Do you feel that that is unavoidable?

Comment: You can get the list of embedded resources, but if you are looking for specific files, I don't see a way around this.  If you know that the ONLY files in the resources are your images, you can just use GetManifestResourceNames()

Comment: Thank you, a combination of GetManifestResourceNames and GetManifestResourceStream will get me very close to the end solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice tutorial on how to extract embedded resources [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/embeddedresources.aspx) on CodeProject, and here is [how](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/AlphaImageImagelist.aspx) to use an image as alpha-blended, and shows how to load it into an image list. Here's a helper class to make loading embedded resources easier [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RERM.aspx).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

How about [this forum answer](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/234431-how-get-embedded-resources-assemblies) that uses [GetManifestResourceStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream(VS.80).aspx) ?

Comment: Thank you for the information, with this approach I need to specify the exact name of the file, is there anyway to avoid that?